# the new look of SE

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I don't know what was the intention behind this new look but the fonts appear so distorted in my system. I use firefox-25.0 on a fedora 19 machine.

Attached a screenshot. (The adjacent browser window shows another site which looks fine, therefore it is not an inherent problem of the browser)

Is anyone else having the same kind of problem ?

[image]

Another screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you mean?  Also which version of firefox?

Comment: I'm using Firefox (25.0.1) on Windows, and haven't had any problems.

Comment: @NickCraver edited the question.. added screenshot

Comment: @WYSIWYG what font is it actually using on your end?  I haven't seen this from any other users, very likely missing fonts.

Comment: @NickCraver.. firefox uses serif. I tried disabling web pages from using their own fonts and it looks fine..but that shouldn't be the way right ?

Comment: @WYSIWYG We don't use a custom font...do you have any extensions and such that are trying to change the font perhaps?  We avoid custom fonts most of the time just for this reason :)